# Deleting new lines once the price crosses

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

The problem is that I do not understand what command I have to make the line go until it intersects with a candle

```
leftLenL = leftLenH
rightLenL = leftLenH

atr1 = ta.atr(10)

atr2 = ta.atr(10)

atr3 = ta.atr(10)

atr4 = ta.atr(10)

atr5 = ta.atr(10)

atr6 = ta.atr(10)

pos1 = close + close * (0.48 /100)
pos2 = close + close * (1.66 /100)
pos3 = close + close * (3.71 /100)

pos4 = close - close * (0.49 /100)
pos5 = close - close * (1.66 /100)
pos6 = close - close * (3.71 /100)

c = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH,rightLenH)
b = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)

plotshape(c ? pos1: na , "100х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "100х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(c ? pos2: na , "50х Ликвилации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "50х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(c ? pos3: na , "25х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "25х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)

plotshape(b ? pos4: na , "100х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "100х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(b ? pos5: na , "50х Ликвилации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "50х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(b ? pos6: na , "25х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "25х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)

//////Lines//////////

bars = +500
n = 1

var line[]  highs = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs2 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs3 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs4 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs5 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs6 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
//Lines
bull = b
bear = c
highestHigh = pos1
highestHigh2 = pos2
highestHigh3 = pos3
lowerlow1 = pos4
lowerlow2 = pos5
lowerlow3 = pos6
if bear     // instead of just drawing a line, we push it into an array, a list of lines so we can loop through the list and perform actions on all lines 
    array.unshift(highs, line.new(bar_index, highestHigh, bar_index + bars, highestHigh, style = line.style_dotted, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
    array.unshift(highs2, line.new(bar_index, highestHigh2, bar_index + bars, highestHigh2, style = line.style_dotted, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
    array.unshift(highs3, line.new(bar_index, highestHigh3, bar_index + bars, highestHigh3, style = line.style_dotted, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
if bull
    array.unshift(highs4, line.new(bar_index, lowerlow1, bar_index + bars, lowerlow1,style = line.style_dotted, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
    array.unshift(highs5, line.new(bar_index, lowerlow2, bar_index + bars, lowerlow2,style = line.style_dotted, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
    array.unshift(highs6, line.new(bar_index, lowerlow3, bar_index + bars, lowerlow3,style = line.style_dotted, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))



for x = (array.size(highs) > 0 ? array.size(highs)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs, x), bar_index+bars) 

for x2 = (array.size(highs2) > 0 ? array.size(highs2)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs2, x2), bar_index+bars)  

for x3 = (array.size(highs3) > 0 ? array.size(highs3)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs3, x3), bar_index+bars)  

for x4 = (array.size(highs4) > 0 ? array.size(highs4)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs4, x4), bar_index+bars)  

for x5 = (array.size(highs5) > 0 ? array.size(highs5)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs5, x5), bar_index+bars)  

for x6 = (array.size(highs6) > 0 ? array.size(highs6)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs6, x6), bar_index+bars)
```

If the line does not intersect, then it must continue to the right until it intersects.

I was able to draw lines through the command

```
 for i2 = (array.size(highs2) > 0 ? array.size(highs2)-1 : na) to 0
```

But with this command I had some of the lines displayed and some not, and I don't understand why

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if price intersects the lines we need to loop an array of lines to check each against the current bar and do this on each bar. Pivot highs are formed above the current price - we can check this group of lines against bar highs as we know we will be below the line initially. Pivot lows are always formed under the low, so we need to check this group of lines against bar lows as we were above initially. So we have 2 groups; 2 arrays of lines. We can make one function to extend the lines - this is easier. We loop each array and extend the lines right. But how do we exclude ones that price has intersected? We need to remove them from the array. So we check each bar high or low to see if it has broke each line, if it has we set the x2 to the current bar and remove it from the array. This way we do not continue to extend it. I have included further notes in the following code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Lines", overlay=true, max_lines_count = 500)

leftLenH  = 20 
rightLenH = 20

leftLenL  = leftLenH
rightLenL = rightLenH

highestHigh  = close + close * (0.48 /100)
highestHigh2 = close + close * (1.66 /100)
highestHigh3 = close + close * (3.71 /100)

lowerlow1 = close - close * (0.49 /100)
lowerlow2 = close - close * (1.66 /100)
lowerlow3 = close - close * (3.71 /100)

bear = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH,rightLenH)
bull = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)

plotshape(bear ? highestHigh : na , "100х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "100х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(bear ? highestHigh2: na , "50х Ликвилации Лонг",  shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "50х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(bear ? highestHigh3: na , "25х Ликвидации Лонг",  shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "25х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)

plotshape(bull ? lowerlow1: na , "100х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "100х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(bull ? lowerlow2: na , "50х Ликвилации Лонг",  shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "50х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(bull ? lowerlow3: na , "25х Ликвидации Лонг",  shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "25х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)

//////Lines//////////

bars = +500
n = 1

var line[]  highs = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  lows  = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 

// Function to add same line type to an array at a given level
addLine(arr, y) =>
    array.unshift(arr, line.new(bar_index, y, bar_index + bars, y, style = line.style_dotted, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))

// Function to loop line array extending right 
extend(arr, len) =>
    for l in arr                 
        line.set_x2(l, len)

// Function to end lines on current bar if significant point breaks line price
// m is used as a multiplier to inverse the bool condition allowing the same function to be used to check for highs or lows 
// a multiplier of 1 is used for highs and -1 for lows to take the inverse of the condition 
// We run the loop backwards to avoid indexing errors when removing elements 
// we remove the line from the array after setting the x2 at the current bar so that we do not continue to extend it to the right 
endLine(arr, m) =>
    p = m > 0 ? high : low // check high or low depending on inverse or not 
    if array.size(arr) > 0
        for i  = array.size(arr)-1 to 0
            l  = array.get(arr, i) 
            lp = line.get_price(l, bar_index)
            if p * m > lp * m // check price against line price. multiply by 1 or -1 for inverse operation 
                line.set_x2(l, bar_index)
                array.remove(arr, i)

if bear     // instead of just drawing a line, we push it into an array, a list of lines so we can loop through the list and perform actions on all lines 
    addLine(highs, highestHigh)
    addLine(highs, highestHigh2)
    addLine(highs, highestHigh3)

if bull
    addLine(lows, lowerlow1)
    addLine(lows, lowerlow2)
    addLine(lows, lowerlow3)

// check highs against pivot highs
// check lows against pivot lows 
// set line at current bar if broken 
// remove from arrays 
endLine(highs, 1)
endLine(lows, -1)

// extend lines in both arrays to the right
extend(highs, bar_index + bars)
extend(lows,  bar_index + bars)
```

** note ** max line count can be adjusted in the indicator() header

Cheers and best of luck with your coding and trading

Comment: The code is a little complicated, but logical and understandable after the explanation, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Cheers and all the best